# Wordpress custom post type and page

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, child-pages

I do using custom post type by lists,

**"Post_type = color"
eg./color**

My **color-archive.php** contain just search form. I delete all while loops!

I want to expose posts within page templates. **eg./color/color-archive**

I tested it, if I am add a `( color )` page. Wp do not open /color/ page and redirect the original **color-archive.php**.

> **It work:**
>
> (/color/ page is masked from /color/ post_type)

I think add a child page from `( color )` **eg./color/new-page** it solved.

But I am worried, `/color/` both a page and custom `post_type` archive page!

Is there a situation will cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your question not so much clear but try the following instruction which i understand.

First you create page template-color.php and than give template name like

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Color
*/
?>
```

Now at admin area you create page color and select template Color. Than hit the url of cutom post type page like `abc.com/color`. 
In this way you can expose posts within page templates.

Answer (score 0):

I think the slug of our page and post-type become the same. Please change any -one of them 
ie, post_type=>'color' and page slug to colors.

Hope it helps